Sharepoint App is able to connect to site but not able to read from the folders
We have created an App for sharepoint(using layouts/15/appregnew.aspx) with the following access on the site XYZ
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
  <AppPermissionRequest Scope="https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/XYZ"  Right="FullControl"/>
</AppPermissionRequests>

We are able to connect to collection using the following code
    sp_url = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/XYZ"
    ctx = ClientContext(sp_url).with_credentials(ClientCredential(client_id, client_secret))
    target_web = ctx.web.get().execute_query()

But we are getting access denied exception in the following code
Exception:

ClientRequestException: ('-2147024891,
System.UnauthorizedAccessException', 'Access denied.', "403 Client
Error: Forbidden for url:
https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/XYZ/_api/Web/lists/GetByTitle('Documents')/RootFolder/Folders/Add('Shared%20Documents%2Fnp%2Fdev%2Fxxx_%231xxx')")

Code

target_list = ctx.web.lists.get_by_title("Documents")
target_folder = target_list.root_folder.folders.add(f"Shared Documents/{tenant}/{env}/{report_name}")

Are we missing some other access? Any help will be appreciated.

Please sure you have the appropriate permissions in your app manifest file.
